# Date Time zone issue in .net on server

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to parse the string 2017-06-02T00:00:00+05:30 in .net and get datetime value as 2017-06-02: 00:00:00. Means server is converting this date to eastern time zone. But I want to store it in given time zone. Any help appreciated.

Comment: given is the time zone parsed from 05:30, or given is the constant 'eastern time zone'? I mean 05:30 might be time zone for multiple choices.

Comment: Also be aware to not try to parse 05:30 into timezone under any circumstances> http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time

Comment: The `DateTime` type can't hold timezone information. You can only get local or UTC time. If you want to preserve the offset, you have to use DateTimeOffset

Answer (score 1):

Because your input contains a time zone offset, and you appear to be asking for a `DateTime` with `.Kind` == `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, you cannot use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`, at least not without altering your input string.  There is no combination of custom formatters (`K`, `zzz`, etc.) and `DateTimeStyles` that will give you back an unspecified kind of `DateTime`.  They will always pick up on the offset and assume you want either local time or UTC.

So, you have some options.

1. Alter your string before parsing, to truncate the offset.

   ```
   string s = "2017-06-02T00:00:00+05:30";
   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s.Substring(0, 19),
                                     "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   ```
2. Parse as a `DateTimeOffset`, then take the `DateTime` property.

   ```
   string s = "2017-06-02T00:00:00+05:30";
   DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s,
                                     "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz",
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   DateTime dt = dto.DateTime;
   ```

Personally, I prefer option 2.  You may even consider just using `DateTimeOffset` throughout.  It's usually a better fit for most scenarios.

Also note that the invariant culture is preferred over the local culture when parsing a string in this format, because the ISO-8601 specification that defines this format always uses the Gregorian calendar system.  If you use other cultures, it's possible to interpret the numbers in a different calendar system, which could lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using DateTimeOffset will give you what you need.

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
string dateString = "2017-06-02T00:00:00+05:30";
DateTimeOffset offset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateString, culture);
// adjustedDateTime should contain 6/2/2017 12:00:00 AM. There are other properties on offset such as LocalDateTime to provide other options
DateTime adjustedDateTime = offset.DateTime;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2017-06-02T00:00:00+05:30", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", culture);
```

Comment: Thanks.But after doing this it is converting the date in eastern time zone. I need datetime in same timezone which I have given. For example I need this "2017-06-02T12:30:00+05:30" as "2017-06-02 12:30:00". But after applying your solution I am getting 2017-06-01 3:00 PM

Comment: Yes, but the `.Kind` property is different. It has the right time, and converted it to server local. The computer knows what time you want. If you output it again for Eastern, it would show the right time.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)